# phpactiverecord if confition

Tags: if-statement, phpactiverecord

i want to ask something related with php activerecord

here'se my code

```
public function validate()
{
        $log = Login::find(1);

        $login = new Login(array(
            'id' => 1,
            'user' => $_POST['user'],
            'pass' => $_POST['pass']
            ));

        if ($this->user = $log->user AND $this->pass = $log->pass | $log->user = $this->user AND $log->pass = $this->pass)
        {
            APP::redirect('dashboard.index');
        }else{
            APP::redirect('dashboard.login');
        }
    }
```

i wonder why my code always redirect to dahsboard.index although the value from input form and database are different. is there something i missed? and english isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes. thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused `=` (assignment) with `==` (comparison). So you'd get a lot of 'TRUE' in that if.